# Unity game on Mac fails in build due to AdMob

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, admob

[image: This is the Log]

This is the log I got. Nothing I found on the web didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to disable "Enable Bitcode" option in XCode Project settings.

[image]

Or just wait until Google will add bitcode support.